# PREVGROUPVAL on Opportunities with Products and Schedules

Tags: reporting, formula, analytics

I have revenue scheduling enabled, so that I can calculate the daily revenue for opportunity line items for a given date range.

I would like to do a YoY report, to see the Q3 2014 (previous quarter) compared to the Q3 2013 (previous quarter, previous year).

With just opportunities, I can do this using the close date and this formula:

```
If(PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM,**CLOSE_DATE**) >0, 
   (AMOUNT:SUM - PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, **CLOSE_DATE**)) / PREVGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, **CLOSE_DATE**), 
   0
)
```

In my report filter I grab close dates that are either between 7/1/13 and 9/30/13 or 7/1/14 and 9/30/14.

With line item schedules I'm using the report type "**Opportunities with Products and Schedules**", but I can't figure out what the field name is for the **Schedule Date** (to use instead of CLOSE_DATE above).
I tried ScheduleDate, Schedule_Date, FiscalScheduleDate, no luck..

I hope someone can help.  Thanks!